# How to go from linear axis to log?

Tags: c++, scale

I have a c++ program which the user will click on two points on the screen and I have to create a logarithym scale from that.. Like:

10     100      1000      10000

given that my first point is at 10 supossed pixel 5 and 10000 is given at pixel 200

So how do I calculate the equation that would make my mouse show the log value when it points to the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what is meant by _logging_. Removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the [`log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log) function. Let's first assume no offset. If you are given a value of `x` on the X-axis, you can get it's log value (e.g. in base 10) by:

```
log(x) / log(10)
```

If you want `x` to count from a certain offset (say `x0`), you should adjust `x`:

```
log(x - x0) / log(10)
```

If you want the resulting point to be offset at a point (say `lx0`), well just do it:

```
log(x - x0) / log(10) + lx0
```

Comment: Note there is also a log10 function.